# Running EF migrations from Package Manager Console gives an error

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a migration on an ASP.NET 5 / EF 7 project. In project.json I have:

```
"dependencies": {
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  // Other dependencies
},

"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://localhost:5000",
  "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
}
```

I ran "dnx ef migrations add 'Start'" on Developer Command Prompt inside the project folder and the migration was created without a problem ...

When I run "ef migrations add 'Start'" on Package Manage Console I get:

```
"ef : The term 'ef' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

I have no idea why I get this error ... The project.json seems fine ...

Am I missing some step here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework doesn't offer this in the Package Manager Console currently. More information can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/978

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing and what I wrote. The question is why do I get an error when running an EF command on Package Manager Console.

Comment: The EF command isn't added anymore (unlike previous versions of EF). You might be able to run dnx ef from your Package Manager Console.